# Lock user from writing values before a default setting one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a terminal command prompt (the user can write on inputbox and press enter and recieves the command from backend) and I am passing a default value from model to my template for my inputbox, but I want to lock it before $ so user cannot go back and write before that

```
$('#textInput').val("Enter").html(this.Template());
```

But how can I do it for part of the inputbox?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that the ``$>`` be inside the input field? Why not think of some clever css-trick that would just place that in the correct position?
Think this would save you a world of hurt.

Comment: Use a content-editable div for the editable part and position it beside a non editable div for the prompt.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think Jordan's solution would be better, given that `content-editable` is not that old and doesn't work in IE8-, and mobile support isn't quite there yet. Reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=editable

Comment: @Tyblitz - `contenteditable` has worked in IE since 5.5, long before it was adopted as standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it graphically, by putting a span overtop of it, or you can attach a JS handler to void out edits that you don't want.

```
$("#textInput").on("change keyup keypress keydown", function(evt) {
    if($(this).val().length < 10) {
        $(this).val("Enter $> ");
    }
});
```

By the way, I'm not sure why you split up Enter from the $> in your example.

Comment: This is a nice working solution, probably the easiest & quickest one. You could also make the terminal consist of 2 boxes, with the `Enter $>` displayed in the first, and the actual code in the second. Then you could concatenate both if necessary. **EDIT:** Well this actually kinda coincides with what you called the 'graphic method'

Comment: Make sure you put my code within document.ready. Also, recopy it please. I accidentally put commas in it, and it should have been spaces only.